# Which jar files to be used for implementing JFreeChart application?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can anybody please suggest which jar files would support all the classes to implement jfree chart and from where to download?

Edit: Is there any way to generate charts using JFreeChart without using AWT and Swing, because I need an image of chart without close, minize and maximize features like an applet.

Answer (score 1):

See [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) and the latest SourceForge [download link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/); note you'll need both `JFreeChart` and `JCommon`.

Comment: Thank you.Could you plz share any url for line chart source code?

Comment: Thank you Graham. Is there any way to generete charts using jfreechart without using AWT and Swing, because I need an image of chart without close, minize and maximize features like an applet.

Comment: @VidyaSagar you may be better of starting a new question but in the meantime take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982110/which-jar-files-to-be-used-for-implementing-jfreechart-application/11982707#comment15976750_11982707) the key command is `createBufferedImage` [API Docs](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#createBufferedImage%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: @GrahamA: Your comment link seems to point to itself; can you update your answer?

Comment: This is the correct [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221816/jfreechart-itext-black-image-when-creating-pdf/11225815#11225815)